# How to display a dialogue to its full width for tablet of 10.1 inch

Tags: android, dialog

I want to display a dialogue whose width should fit the screen size of a tablet , can anyone let me how to do it, I tried setting the width , but did not succeed in it.

The code is as below:

```
            final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            Window window = nagDialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
            wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            wlp.width= WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            window.setAttributes(wlp);
            getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popuplayout);
            nagDialog.show();
```

the popuplayout.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_marginLeft="347dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="163dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code and explain what happened.

Comment: I am not able to modify the width of the dialogue

Answer (score 0):

Set Width and Height of Parent Laoyout to match_paren i.e R.layout.popuplayout

Answer (score 0):

dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Answer (score 0):

```
final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popuplayout);// note here!!!!

        Window window = nagDialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        wlp.width= WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        nagDialog.show();
```

Please **do not** setAttributes **before** using setContentView(R.layout.xxx) method.
Make sure you call setContentView(R.layout.xxx) method first, then change dialog window's attribute.